# Laggy Custom Transition between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

So I want to customize Viewcontroller Presentation because using my code the `viewcontroller` freezes for half a second and then presents the other `viewcontroller`.

```
extension UIViewController {

func presentDetail (_ viewControllerToPresent : UIViewController) {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = .push
    transition.subtype = .fromLeft
    self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: this is not the actual way to implement custom viewcontroller transitions. Random tutorial is [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/322-custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

For a custom presentation you'll need to provide a transitionDelegate on the presentedView and then provide required animator objects.

The minimum possible implementation seems to be to provide a UIPresentationController in `func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController?`